# How to clear an ajax form after submit?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, submit

the following is the ajax markup for processing my form:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: "get",
    url: "ajax.php?action=add_driver",
    data: $("#addDriver").serialize(),

    beforeSend: function(){
        $('.error, .success, .notice').remove();
    },

    success: function(json){
        if (json['status']=='success')
        {
            alert(json['message']);
            $("#addDriver").reset();
        }else{
            if(json['error']['my_variable']){
            $("input[name=my_variable]").after('<div class="error">'+json['error']['my_variable']+'</div>');    
            }
            $("#addDriver").reset();
        }
});
```

what I want to know is, how would i clear the form, once it has been submitted? I tired using `$("#addDriver").reset();` but it just clears the form completely without submitting the form. Any help?

Comment: I'm a little confused here. You want to clear the form, .reset() does that but.....??? what??

Comment: If the `reset()` is in the success then it will do it after submit.  What are you expecting to happen that isn't?

Comment: I formatted your code a bit to highlight the fact that you seem to be missing a `}` on the end of the `success:` handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's not a question of `how?`, in your case, but of `when?`.

`$("#addDriver")[0].reset();` should be just fine, provided that is id of your form, as long as you use it within `success()` or `complete()` callback function.

Comment: @RobertMartens you may want to put it next line after your alert in case you only need to reset form when you succeed

Comment: Ok, I have edited your code for readability. You have placed reset in correct callback function, but it will be activated ONLY if json['status'] is NOT 'success'.

Comment: @Krule, the reset function should only be activated once, the json is a success, and the alert message has been shown...

Comment: Then, place it just before or after alert.

Comment: @krule, ive put it after the alert, but i'm getting an error, saying `TypeError: $(...).reset is not a function`

Comment: I was pretty sure that used to work. But, `$(...)[0].reset()` will work.